# List of entity in symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to list all of my entity in a twig page.

I want to make a array of my entity and send the array in my twig page.

This is my entity list:

[image: list of entity]

ps: sorry for my English

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array/list of entities from Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031534/get-array-list-of-entities-from-doctrine)

Comment: Stackoverflow typically deals with questions as opposed to statements.

Comment: list containing the names of your project entities? or list of instances of a specific entity? please to be more clear, ideally with an example of the final array

Answer (score 2):

According to the comment from @MKhalidJunaid and this link

[Get array/list of entities from Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031534/get-array-list-of-entities-from-doctrine)

This is your solution.

**AppController.php**

```
public function entitiesAction() {
    $entities= [];
    $metas = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
    foreach ($metas as $meta) {
        $entities[] = $meta->getName();
    }
    
    return render('entities.html.twig', [
           'entities' => $entities
    ]);
}
```

**entities.html.twig**

```
<ul>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <li>{{ entity }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```