# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine - Iterate all entity classes

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework2, zend-db

Is there a good way to iterate all entity classes (across different modules) in Zend Framwork 2?

I already tried to go by Doctrine's EntityManager:

```
$entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getLoadedMetadata();
```

but that does only return an empty array.

I know that one could probably do this by [iterating all Classes in specific Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761554/php-get-all-class-names-inside-a-particular-namespace), but that seems like a lot of overhead.

Is there maybe some way that I am missing?

Comment: What did you try, what went wrong, etc etc? I literally ran a search "doctrine get all entity classes" and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031534/get-array-list-of-entities-from-doctrine) as the first hit. (Note: linked answer uses `getAllMetadata()` instead of `getLoadedMetadata()`)

Comment: Thank you, @rkeet, this was a stupid mistake on my part. I meant to change it back tou `getAllMetadata()` but didn't. Very embarassing.