# How to globally disable doctrine auto generated fields?

Tags: php, doctrine

## Objective

I want to disable GeneratedValue of doctrine without updating the entities.

## Context

I have two applications, an old one and the new version.

I'm creating a Php script to migrate the data from the old database to the new database.

On the new application there is Doctrine.

## Problem

For now I copy paste all my entities each time I do a change on the new application.

But I have to change the Entities to remove the annotations for the auto generted values

```php
* @ORM\GeneratedValue
```

If I don't the ID won't be se same on the new and the old database.

For example I don't have a user with the ID 500, so when a migrate the users the user supposed to be ID 501 will be 500.

So my first objective is to disable the auto generated, so that when I copy paste the entities I don't have to changes things on it.

Maybe I can change the generation strategy globally ?

```php
$isDevMode = true;
$proxyDir = null;
$cache = null;
$useSimpleAnnotationReader = false;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
    [PROJECT_ROOT . "/Entities"],
    $isDevMode,
    $proxyDir,
    $cache,
    $useSimpleAnnotationReader
);


$queryCache = new ArrayAdapter();
$metadataCache = new ArrayAdapter();
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);


$config->setQueryCache($queryCache);
$config->setMetadataCache($metadataCache);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = [
   'url' => 'postgres://user:password@db/database?serverVersion=14.2',
];

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two posts that helped me:

- [Get array/list of entities from Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031534/get-array-list-of-entities-from-doctrine)
- [Explicitly set Id with Doctrine when using "AUTO" strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301285/explicitly-set-id-with-doctrine-when-using-auto-strategy)

After the entity manager creation I disable the id generator for each entities.

```php
// [...]
// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

$metas = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
    $metadata->setIdGenerator(new AssignedGenerator());
}
```